# Calculate integral using rectangle method in Pascal gives 0 while in C++ good results

Tags: c++, pascal, integral

I'm trying to implement the rectangle method in Pascal. The point is, I'm getting wrong results. I'm getting 0, while the same code in C++ gives me good results. Why is that? Thanks.

Pascal:

```
Program HelloWorld(output);

function degrees2radians(x: real) : real;
var
   result: real;
begin
   result := x * 3.14159 / 180.0;
end;

function fun1(x: real) : real;
var 
    result: real;
begin
    x := degrees2radians(x);
    result := Sin(x);
end;

function rect_method(a: real; b: real; n: integer) : real;
var
    result: real;
    h: real;
    integral: real;
    i : integer;
begin
    integral := 0;
    i := 0;
    h := (a - b) / n;
    for i := 1  to n do
    begin
        integral := integral + fun1(b + i*h)*h;
    end;
    result := integral;
end;

var
   result: real;

begin
  result := rect_method(1.0, -2.0, 3);
  writeln('result = ', result);
end.
```

And C++ (which works: https://onlinegdb.com/ubuNQInB2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

double degrees2radians(double x)
{
    return x * 3.14159 / 180;
}

double f1(double x)
{
    x = degrees2radians(x);
    return sin(x);
}

double rectangle_method(double a, double b, int n)
{
    float h, integral = 0;
    h = (a - b) / (double) n;

    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
        integral += f1(b + i*h)*h;

    return integral;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << rectangle_method(1, -2, 3) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Why is that?* -- Print out the intermediate values to see where the differences start to occur.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: It's strange because when I tried, it seems values are completly different. I don't know why, because I wrote both codes!

Comment: Is the correct result `8.32872e-10`? That might be just floating-point error. The values of `f1(b + i*h)*h` for `i = 1,2,3` are `-1.7452391697363297E-002`, `0` and `1.7452391697363297E-002`. You get exactly zero if you add them up

Comment: None of your Pascal functions actually return a value. You seem to believe that `result` has some magical meaning in Pascal, that assigning a value to a variable named `result` would have the function return that value. This is not the case; `result` is a local variable like any other.

Comment: Why are `h` and `integral` of `float` type in the C++ snippet? All the other variables are `double`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Pascal code `result` is a local variable, which has nothing to do with [the special identifier called `result`](https://wiki.freepascal.org/Function) that you want to use:

```pascal
function degrees2radians(x: real) : real;
var
   result: real;
begin
   result := x * 3.14159 / 180.0;
end;
```

You should remove `result: real;` in all your functions.

---

However, "fixed" code produces zero anyway: https://onlinegdb.com/_M2pGk134, which is actually correct. That is, this code should return zero.

I rewrote this code in Julia (the language doesn't matter, the point is that it supports high-precision floating-point types out of the box; `BigFloat` is such a high-precision float), and the result is still zero:

```
degrees2radians(x::Real)::Real = x * 3.14159 / 180

f1(x::Real) = sin(degrees2radians(x))

function rectangle_method(a::Real, b::Real, n::Integer)
    integral = 0
    h = (a - b) / n;

    for i in 1:n
      @show i f1(b + i*h)*h
      integral += f1(b + i*h)*h;
    end

    return integral;
end

@show rectangle_method(BigFloat("1"), -BigFloat("2"), 3)
```

The output looks like this:

```
i = 1
f1(b + i * h) * h = -0.01745239169736329549313317881927049082689975241899824937795751704833664190229729
i = 2
f1(b + i * h) * h = 0.0
i = 3
f1(b + i * h) * h = 0.01745239169736329549313317881927049082689975241899824937795751704833664190229729
rectangle_method(BigFloat("1"), -(BigFloat("2")), 3) = 0.0
```

So, `f1(b + 2 * h) * h` is zero, and `f1(b + 1 * h) * h` is *exactly* (look at the amount of digits after the decimal point!) the negative of `f1(b + 3 * h) * h`, so they cancel out in the `integral` sum, resulting in zero.

Comment: I agree that is appears that zero is the correct answer. I believe that the C++ code in the question has some rounding errors. The Pascal code in the question is not equivalent to the C++ code (even after correcting the problem with result). The equivalent Pascal actually produces the result 8.3E-10. I'm pretty sure that if the rounding errors in the C++ code are fixed the result will be zero.